# SSRS report does not load from corporate office

Tags: reporting-services, fiddler, ssrs-2012

My SSRS report does not load when I am accessing it from a corporate office. I can access it from anywhere else (that I've tried so far) except for said office. The office environment is using XP with .Net 2.0 installed and accessing the report from IE8. The SSRS version is 2012 SP1. I've provided additional details below. Does anybody see anything that might be causing this issue? Many thanks in advance and let me know if I need to post additional information.

Here's the Fiddler overview - I can provide more Fiddler detail if need be:
[image]

Here's the Fiddler from a different server where the report loaded successfully:
[image]

Here is the SSRS log file:

```
.library!ReportServer_0-81!19c8!02/24/2014-17:20:52:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!19c8!02/24/2014-17:20:52:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/, PathBased).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!19c8!02/24/2014-17:20:52:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/, PathBased).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!19c8!02/24/2014-17:20:52:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
.library!ReportServer_0-81!1938!02/24/2014-17:20:52:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!1938!02/24/2014-17:20:52:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:21:03:: e ERROR: WriteCallback(): failed to write in write callback.
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:21:03:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x04D4, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.rshost!rshost!19c8!02/24/2014-17:21:03:: e ERROR: HttpPipelineCallback::SendResponse(): failed async writing response.
.rshost!rshost!19c8!02/24/2014-17:21:03:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x04D4, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.httpruntime!ReportManager_0-80!19c8!02/24/2014-17:21:03:: e ERROR: Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704D4): The network connection was aborted by the local system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704D4)
.   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.HostingInterfaces.IRsHttpPipeline.SendResponse(Void* response, Boolean finalWrite, Boolean closeConn)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.library!ReportManager_0-80!19c8!02/24/2014-17:21:03:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: RsWorkerRequest::FlushResponse., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-80-130377341248782112.  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704D4): The network connection was aborted by the local system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704D4)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
.library!ReportServer_0-81!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:40:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/America's Auto Auction Inc).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:21:40:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/America's Auto Auction Inc, PathBased).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:40:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/America's Auto Auction Inc, PathBased).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:21:40:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
.library!ReportServer_0-81!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:40:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/America's Auto Auction Inc, False).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:21:40:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:21:53:: e ERROR: WriteCallback(): failed to write in write callback.
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:21:53:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x04D4, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.rshost!rshost!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:53:: e ERROR: HttpPipelineCallback::SendResponse(): failed async writing response.
.rshost!rshost!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:53:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x04D4, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.httpruntime!ReportManager_0-80!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:53:: e ERROR: Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704D4): The network connection was aborted by the local system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704D4)
.   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.HostingInterfaces.IRsHttpPipeline.SendResponse(Void* response, Boolean finalWrite, Boolean closeConn)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.library!ReportManager_0-80!1230!02/24/2014-17:21:53:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: RsWorkerRequest::FlushResponse., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-80-130377341248782112.  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704D4): The network connection was aborted by the local system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704D4)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:22:03:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/America's Auto Auction Inc/America's Auto Auction Summary).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:22:03:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:22:03:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/America's Auto Auction Inc/America's Auto Auction Summary, PathBased).
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:22:03:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
.library!ReportServer_0-81!3d8!02/24/2014-17:22:03:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:22:23:: e ERROR: WriteCallback(): failed to write in write callback.
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:22:23:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x03E3, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.rshost!rshost!1230!02/24/2014-17:22:23:: e ERROR: HttpPipelineCallback::SendResponse(): failed async writing response.
.rshost!rshost!1230!02/24/2014-17:22:23:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x03E3, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.httpruntime!ReportManager_0-80!1230!02/24/2014-17:22:23:: e ERROR: Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
.   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.HostingInterfaces.IRsHttpPipeline.SendResponse(Void* response, Boolean finalWrite, Boolean closeConn)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.library!ReportManager_0-80!1230!02/24/2014-17:22:23:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: RsWorkerRequest::FlushResponse., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-80-130377341248782112.  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
.library!WindowsService_157!1994!02/24/2014-17:27:17:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
.library!WindowsService_157!1994!02/24/2014-17:27:17:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 1 sessions, 0 cache entries, 0 snapshots, 0 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 0 segments, 0 segment mappings, 0 edit sessions.
.library!WindowsService_157!1994!02/24/2014-17:27:17:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:35:01:: e ERROR: WriteCallback(): failed to write in write callback.
.rshost!rshost!654!02/24/2014-17:35:01:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x0079, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.rshost!rshost!1230!02/24/2014-17:35:01:: e ERROR: HttpPipelineCallback::SendResponse(): failed async writing response.
.rshost!rshost!1230!02/24/2014-17:35:01:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x0079, pipeline=0x00000002500A7EC0.
.httpruntime!ReportManager_0-80!1230!02/24/2014-17:35:01:: e ERROR: Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070079): The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070079)
.   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.HostingInterfaces.IRsHttpPipeline.SendResponse(Void* response, Boolean finalWrite, Boolean closeConn)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.library!ReportManager_0-80!1230!02/24/2014-17:35:01:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: RsWorkerRequest::FlushResponse., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-80-130377341248782112.  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070079): The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070079)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
.   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

Edit: I've just received this error for the first time. Up until now, the page has been blank and stuck at loading.
[image]

Comment: I wonder if reporting services 2012 requires IE10 and up. What version of IE is running for those which do run?

Comment: @Energ1ser For those that do run, I'm using IE11 but emulating IE10. I have tried emulating IE 7-10 and all of those work. The host machine where it doesn't work is using IE 8 Compatibility View (which I believe reverts to IE 7?).

Comment: Can you provide larger, more readable screenshots.

Comment: @Energ1ser Can you right click and open them in a new tab? Then it'll be the size as I uploaded it.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are accessing the same report from the same report server from the client PCs that are working?

Comment: @Nathan Yes. The SSRS reports are hosted on the stand-alone SSRS web server. Client PCs that are not accessing the reports from the corporate office all work when loading the report.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  I do not have a solution; however I wanted to point out some key details.

The problem only occurs with IE11 running under compatibility mode of "Edge".  It works fine when running with compatibility mode of IE10.  Also, it works fine with Firefox & Chrome.

The problem does not occur with all reports; however, it does occur with two different clients.  Both are running SQL Server 2008R2.